# Add one exclude filter for all language codes

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have website with many languages with address like
`http://domain.com/<lang>/`

I would like to create exclude filter in one of my views to report global traffic but i don't want to create dozen of exclude filter for each country (easy to forget to add some lang code).

Is this right to use custom exclude filter for `Request URI` with regex like `^\/[a-z]{2}\/` to exclude all requests which begins with `/xx/` like `/en/` `/de/` etc.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried it? What is wrong with it, what issue do you get when using that pattern? FYI, the final slash may be optional, right? Then, I'd rather use `^/[a-z]{2}(/|$)` (note there is no need escaping `/` in GA regex).

Comment: Thanks, it works. I wanted also have some kind of confirmation that i am thinking in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^/[a-z]{2}(/|$)
```

There is no need escaping `/` in GA regex and `(/|$)` (*match `/` or end of string*) alternation group will make the `/` optional at the end of the input.